# Retire internal Windows root CA

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, certificate-authority, pki

A former colleague created an internal root CA named CA1 with server2008. During migration to a newer OS version a Server CA2 was created and CA1 turned off. Now my problem is, all systems still think they have to ask CA1 to get new certificates. So how do I tell them that CA1 does not exist anymore and they have to ask CA2?

If I open pkiview.msc on one of these servers it lists both servers as certificate authorithies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decommission old CA from Active Directory using the following TechNet Wiki article: [How to Decommission a Windows Enterprise Certification Authority and How to Remove All Related Objects](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3527.how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-how-to-remove-all-related-objects.aspx)

since your old CA is off, you need to complete only steps: 6, 7 and 9. Other steps are not applicable. After cleaning Active Directory from old CA remnants, make sure it will never be powered on.

Answer (score 0):

If someone, is looking for the complete Way

[You can take a look here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-migrating-the-active-directory-certificate-service/ba-p/697674)